# How to replace character in URL in nginx?

Tags: nginx

In my url i have parameter:

```
LAYERS=003100000806,002000000445,003100000813,003100000822,00310000080C
```

In nginx config i get it:

```
if ($request_uri ~* LAYERS=([^&]*)) {
    set $layers $1;
}
```

But now i want to replace `,` to `_` so i want to get:

```
003100000806_002000000445_003100000813_003100000822_00310000080C
```

I found alot `replace` examples but it's change one character or url single part. How can i replace all commas?

I tried:

```
if ($layers ~* ([^,]*)){
        rewrite (.*),(.*) $1_$2 permanent;          
}
```

But still get commas.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the LAYERS argument is available as the `$arg_LAYERS` variable. But this process is easier to achieve using the `$args` variable, which contains everything in the URI following the `?`.

If you have a variable number of `,`s, you can replace them one at a time by capturing the contents of `$args` both before and after the `,`.

For example:

```
if ($args ~ ^(.+&|)(LAYERS=[^&]+),(.*)$) {
    return 301 $uri?$1$2_$3;
}
```